# Use Special Characters in ConverterParameter-Value

Tags: wpf, binding, parameters, special-characters, converters

There is this [MSDN article about spcial characters in WPF/XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970677.aspx):

But those Things seems not to work in XAML Attributes:

```
<MyControl Text={Binding SomeProperty, Converter={StaticResource SomeConverter}, ConverterParameter=Key&#61;Value;/>
```

I want to pass `"Key=Value;"` to the `ConverterParameter`.

For the moment I solved the problem this way:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
    <Binding Path="LengthVersionList" Converter="{StaticResource LengthVersionListFilterConverter}">
        <Binding.ConverterParameter>
            <!-- Type=Singular; -->
            Type&#61;Singular;
        </Binding.ConverterParameter>
    </Binding>
</ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
```

But 7 Lines of Code for a simple assignment? Is there any way to do this in a single line?

***Edit***

Ok, got it to 3 Lines:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
    <Binding Path="LengthVersionList" Converter="{StaticResource LengthVersionListFilterConverter}" ConverterParameter="Type&#61;Plural;" />
</ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
```

But if somebody would have a one-line solution I would be very pleased.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use single quotes instead of double:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding LengthVersionList, Converter={StaticResource LengthVersionListFilterConverter}, ConverterParameter='Type&#61;Plural;'}" />
```